Can i use ::before or ::after on shadow host (:host)?
I am trying to use the ::before or ::after selector on a shadow host but it seems that it doesn't work.
:host(::before) {
  content: "",
  position: absolute;
  inset:0px;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

I would like to know if this is possible or not or maybe if i am missing something. Thanks a lot

You can, but the syntax is :host ::before { /* ... */ }

sing ::before and ::after pseudo-elements directly on a shadow host (:host) is not supported in the current specifications of the Shadow DOM. These pseudo-elements are designed to work with regular DOM elements but not with the shadow host itself.
If you need to add content before or after the shadow host, you have a few alternatives:
Style the shadow host with regular CSS:


class MyElement extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    const shadow = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
    shadow.innerHTML = `
      <div class="before-content">Before content</div>
      <div>Shadow DOM content</div>
      <div class="after-content">After content</div>
      <style>
        .before-content {
          /* styles for before content */
        }
        .after-content {
          /* styles for after content */
        }
      </style>
    `;
  }
}

customElements.define('my-element', MyElement);
:host {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}



This way, you can achieve similar effects without relying on the unsupported ::before and ::after pseudo-elements on the shadow host.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
